# Flutter TabBar with SliverAppBar doesn't keep scroll state

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement a SliverAppBar with Tabs.

I followed this code

[tensor-programming
/
flutter_scroll_tab_tutorial
Watch](https://github.com/tensor-programming/flutter_scroll_tab_tutorial/blob/master/lib/main.dart)

but the behavior of scrolling is very weird, the state is not kept and if you scroll one tab the other tabs will scroll too!!

How can I implement this correctly without sharing scroll between tabs and without losing scroll state??

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;
  ScrollController _scrollViewController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 2);
    _scrollViewController = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 0.0);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    _scrollViewController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // return DefaultTabController(
    //   length: 2,
    //       child: Scaffold(
    //     appBar: AppBar(
    //       title: Text('Example App'),
    //       bottom: TabBar(
    //         tabs: <Widget>[
    //           Tab(
    //             text: "Home",
    //             icon: Icon(Icons.home),
    //           ),
    //           Tab(
    //             text: "Example page",
    //             icon: Icon(Icons.help),
    //           )
    //         ],
    //       ),
    //     ),

    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        controller: _scrollViewController,
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool boxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              title: Text('Tab Controller Example'),
              pinned: true,
              floating: true,
              forceElevated: boxIsScrolled,
              bottom: TabBar(
                tabs: <Widget>[
                  Tab(
                    text: "Home",
                    icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    text: "Example page",
                    icon: Icon(Icons.help),
                  )
                ],
                controller: _tabController,
              ),
            )
          ];
        },
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            PageOne(),
            PageTwo(),
          ],
          controller: _tabController,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.control_point),
        onPressed: () {
          _tabController.animateTo(1,
              curve: Curves.bounceInOut, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 10));

          // _scrollViewController.animateTo(
          //     _scrollViewController.position.minScrollExtent,
          //     duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
          //     curve: Curves.decelerate);

          _scrollViewController
              .jumpTo(_scrollViewController.position.maxScrollExtent);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageOne extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemExtent: 250.0,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Material(
              elevation: 4.0,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.cyan : Colors.deepOrange,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(index.toString()),
              ),
            ),
          ),
    );
  }
}

class PageTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemExtent: 250.0,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Material(
              elevation: 4.0,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.cyan : Colors.deepOrange,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(index.toString()),
              ),
            ),
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
_scrollViewController = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 0.0);
```

Into this

```
_scrollViewController = ScrollController();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Scaffold` widget from the tree. You should either be using a `Scaffold` or `Sliverbar`